# Javascript destructuring: copy class variables by reference to allow assigning and modifying values

Tags: javascript, destructuring, ecma

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.points = [];
    // I need to call this after the components are mounted
    // So keeping the setup separate
    this.setupMyClass();
  }

  setupMyClass() {
    let {points} = this;
    points = [...points, {x: 20, y:20}];

    // ugly code 
    // need to repeat 'this.' everytime I use the variable
    // this.points = [...this.points, {x: 20, y: 20}];

    console.log('points', points);
    console.log('this.points', this.points);
  }
}

myClassInstance = new MyClass();
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g6js3odn/)

Output:

```
points: [{..}]
this.points: []
```

I thought arrays were sent by reference while other values are copied by value. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46323547/3125070) supports the same. What's happening here?

I need to access variables of `MyClass` in a neat way, how do I do it?

Comment: Why do you not use `this.points = points`?

Comment: Why not `this.points.push({x: 20, y:20})`?

Comment: @javrd now I need to keep track of what variables I changed and what I didn't. Or assign back all local vars to class variables at the end?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran No, it doesn't. The push thing is much better here, I misunderstood the point x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because

```
[...points, {x: 20, y:20}];
```

created a new array.

```
let {points} = this;
```

originally points to the points array belonging to the class instance, but

```
points = [...points, {x: 20, y:20}];
```

changes the reference.

You can use `.push` to maintain the reference as:

```
points.push({x: 20, y:20});
```

**EDIT to explain more verbose-ally:**

`[...points, {x: 20, y:20}]` creates a new array, so assigning the new array to points does not change the data the `points` variable(think pointer) *points* to, but rather changes the pointer itself to a new memory location.

Comment: As I already explained,  `[...points, {x: 20, y:20}]` created a new array, so assigning the new array to `points` does not change the data the `points` variable(think pointer) _points_ to, but rather changes the pointer itself to a new memory location.

Comment: so it is indeed assigning by reference! just understood the point made: i'm throwing away _that_ reference by assigning a new one

Answer (score 2):

When using `let {points} = this;`, the `points` variable contains a value and that value is the reference to your array.
So when you edit a property of that array as is done in the answer you linked, you modify the referenced array.

But in your case you use `points = [...points, {x: 20, y:20}];`. Here you assign a new value (a reference to your newly created array) to `points`, and so the reference to the old array is gone.

In this case you can simply use `this.points = [...points, {x: 20, y:20}];` in order to assign it to the `this`, or push your object directly to `this.points` using `this.points.push({x: 20, y:20})`. (For the latter, you don't need to use a destructuring assignment in the first place.)